# Updating modules and core ERROR filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: drupal, xampp, git-bash, drupal-8, drush

I looked at similar questions but I could not find the answer.

Context: **Windows 10, XAMPP, Git, Composer, Drush 8 and Drupal 8.**

When I try to use:

(For modules and themes update) **drush pm-update**

or

(For Core update) **drush up drupal**

**I received the following error:**

```
Illegal string offset 'site' backend.inc:1037                        [warning]
The command could not be executed successfully (returned: The        [error]
filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
, code: 1)
pm-updatestatus failed.
```

But **I don´t have problems**, for examples, downloading, enabling, rebuilding the cache, etc, etc, with Drush.

I can also update modules through Drupal (extend>update).

I tried with

**drush pm-update --debug --verbose**

*And this is an extract with one warning and two errors.*

```
Backend invoke:                                                        [command]
"C:\\Users\\Usuario\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\drush\\drush\\drush"
 --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mysite"
--uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [4.59 sec, 14.67 MB]
"C:\\Users\\Usuario\\AppData\\Roaming\\Composer\\vendor\\drush\\drush\\drush"   [notice]
 --backend=2 --verbose --debug --root="C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mysite"
--uri=http://default  pm-updatestatus 2>&1 [4.59 sec, 14.68 MB]
Illegal string offset 'site' backend.inc:1037 [4.8 sec, 14.68 MB]    [warning]
The command could not be executed successfully (returned: The        [error]
filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
, code: 1) [4.8 sec, 14.68 MB]
pm-updatestatus failed. [4.8 sec, 14.67 MB]                          [error]
Returned from hook drush_pm_updatecode [4.8 sec, 14.67 MB]               [debug]
Changes made in drush_pm_updatecode have been rolled back. [4.8 sec,     [debug]
14.67 MB]
Command dispatch complete [4.81 sec, 14.65 MB]                          [notice]
Returned from hook drush_pm_update [4.81 sec, 14.63 MB]                  [debug]
Command dispatch complete [4.81 sec, 14.6 MB]
```

Honestly... I´m stuck. I´m new with Drupal and I could not find an answer for this issue.

Anyone had this problem? Or know why?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am getting similar issue but have not figured out a solution. I came across the following post but has not helped me resolve my issue. You may give it a try. https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/1839

Comment: I don't have an answer for this issue, but Drupal 8 devs should really be using Composer to manage their modules. Composer's actually required for Drupal Commerce so it'll also be beneficial to be comfortable with it should your Drupal site(s) end up needing an ecommerce solution.

Comment: @peter did you find the solution?